# aws network load balancer ping fail from terminal

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group, amazon-elb, aws-nlb

We have configured our website server with network load balancing. When we tried to ping our domain name using terminal all ping lost.

I tried to figure it out and have no clue how to configure NLB to listen ping from terminal.

Comment: Is even ping supported for nlb?

Comment: i don't know i am new. Is't it possible?

Answer (score 2):

> You need to create one/ multiple listeners in case of NLB and route them to specific target for serving the intended requests

Network traffic that does not match a configured listener is classified as unintended traffic. ICMP requests other than Type 3 (unreachable) are also considered unintended traffic. Network Load Balancers drop unintended traffic without forwarding it to any targets.

Source : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-listeners.html